# Limit order matching - same time

Tags: limit-order

Given these two orders with the same size:

```
Buy  x for 20
Sell x for 15
```

What price are they matched/should they be matched if we have no time priority? Are there any market **standards** to solve this case?

I read that in most systems there is price/time priority but in this case the assumption is, there is no way to figure out which order was first because we are on a blockchain and in this case, both have the same time stamp.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The trade will be executed at 17.5, and both should be happy?

Comment: Thanks for the answer/ That is one option to solve it. If this is the widely used implementation - or industry standard in exchanges, I would be happy if you could also send some proof to this claim.